# Sending Emails from Excel - No Errors but no Output

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a macro that should create an email with variable recipients and details within the body of the email depending on input into the relevant row on the worksheet. It should generate an email per row where 'To do' is present in column P.

I currently have a sub coded with everything I think I need and when I run the macro no errors appear, unfortunately it does not open any template emails as intended either.

I'll admit that my VBA is basic at best but any assistance with the below would be great.

```
Sub Sendmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ClientEmail As Range
    Dim PlannerName As String
    Dim Salutation As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value = "Planner1 Initials" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "To do" Then

            Set ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
            PlannerName = "Planner1 Name"
            Set Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "Planner1@email.com"
                .Subject = "Annual Review"
                .Body = "send email to" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Dear" & xClientSaluation & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "body" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Best wishes" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "" & PlannerName
                .Display

            End With

        ElseIf cell.Value = "Planner2 Initials" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "To do" Then

            Set ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
            PlannerName = "Planner2 Name"
            Set Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "Planner2@email.com"
                .Subject = "Annual Review"
                .Body = "send email to" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Dear" & xClientSaluation & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "body" & vbNewLine & _
                    "Best wishes" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "" & PlannerName
                .Display

            End With

        ElseIf cell.Value = "Planner3 Initials" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "To do" Then

            Set ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
            PlannerName = "Planner3 Name"
            Set Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "Planner3@email.com"
                .Subject = "Annual Review"
                .Body = "send email to" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Dear" & xClientSaluation & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Body " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Best wishes" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "" & PlannerName
                .Display

            End With

        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Appreciate that you likely don't need to repeat for each different set of initials as I have done above but was struggling to set a range without an object error.

The data held in the worksheet columns for context

F = Client Owner Initials

P = If an email needs to be sent, input either No, To Do, Yes or n/a

D = Client's salutation

Thanks,

BIG TWON

Thanks to Krib below, I am now getting Object required error on the following line, I imagine this will repeat throughout:

```
Set ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
```

Comment: you could first of remove the errorhandler so you can see where it gets an error with srepping through it with `F8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think I can see three issues:**

---

```
LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "To do" Then
```

LCase will be seeing "**t**o do", not "**T**o do" so your main block(s) will never run.

Change them to:

```
LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "to do" Then
```

---

Also, as per your recent update, the line:

```
Set ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
```

Is trying to load the `.Value` of a cell into `ClientEmail`

Unfortunately, you have declared it a `Range`:

```
Dim ClientEmail As Range
```

From the looks of your code, you should be declaring it `As String`. But remember, you don't `Set` strings. You just load to them e.g:

```
ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
```

---

Further to above point, you also do:

```
Dim Salutation As Range
```

and

```
Set Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)
```

Which should be:

```
Dim Salutation As String
```

and..

```
Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)
```

---

**So to wrap up..**

Your declarations should look like this:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim ClientEmail As String
Dim PlannerName As String
Dim Salutation As String
```

Your IF statement(s) should look like this (change PlannerX each time):

```
If cell.Value = "Planner1 Initials" And LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "to do" Then
```

And your variable settings should look like this (again, change PlannerX each time):

```
        ClientEmail = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value)
        PlannerName = "Planner1 Name"
        Salutation = LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value)
```

Comment: **This** is exactly why your third port of call when you have an 'invisible' error should be to step through the code with F8.  (Step 1?  Make sure you have "Option Explicit" at the top.  Step 2? Comment out "On Error" lines.  Step 4?  Internet Websearch Engine of your choice.  Step *"I've-run-out-of-other-steps-to-try"*?  Open a Stack Exchange question, with the results of the previous steps.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out...

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm